# Do I need to retain ownership on my custom NSURLConnection wrapper object? (In ARC environment)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, ios-4.2

Note: [This similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829653/ios4-implementation-of-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletio) talks about how to build the same class, but doesn't address my memory management issues related to using the class.

I would like to use `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`, however I need to support iOS 4.2.  Thus, I created a custom class called `JCURLRequest` that uses `NSURLConnection` and generates an nice interface:

```
- (void)sendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
    responseHandler:(JCURLResponseHandler)responseHandler;
```

I have a question about using this class (I'm in ARC memory management):

- When I create my JCURLRequest object do i need to retain a reference to that object?  Or can I just "fire and forget it"?

Note: I understand the basics of ARC - if you have a pointer to an object, it will be kept alive, if there are no more pointers to an object, it will be release in the next auto-release pool.

Thus, I want to know - can I call it like (1) or do i need to use (2)

(1)

```
JCURLRequest *jcURLRequest = [[JCURLRequest alloc] init];
[jcURLRequest sendRequest:myRequest
          responseHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) { ... }];
// Assuming I don't maintain a reference to jcURLRequest after this
```

(2)

```
// Assume @property (strong) JCURLRequest *jcURLRequest;
//        @synthesize jcURLRequest = _jcURLRequest;
self.jcURLRequest = [[JCURLRequest alloc] init];   
[self.jcURLRequest sendRequest:myRequest
          responseHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) { ... }];
```

`NSURLConnection` uses an asynchronous callback, so my thought is that I have to use (2).  This is because - by the time the delegate callback "calls back", the jcURLRequest instance could have been cleaned up in an auto-release pool.

I'm confused though, because I've tested with (1) and it "seems" to work fine.  But, my thought is that maybe it's just coincidence that it's working- ie. really there are no more valid pointers to the jcURLRequest object but the iOS just hasn't gotten around to deallocating it.

Below is the full `JCURLRequest` class for reference

```
//  JCURLRequest.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^JCURLResponseHandler) (NSData *data, NSError *error);

@interface JCURLRequest : NSObject
- (void)sendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request responseHandler:(JCURLResponseHandler)responseHandler;
@end



//  JCURLRequest.m
#import "JCURLRequest.h"

@interface JCURLRequest ()
{
    JCURLResponseHandler responseHandler;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *responseData;
@end

@implementation JCURLRequest
@synthesize responseData = _responseData;


#pragma mark - Public API

- (void)sendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request responseHandler:(JCURLResponseHandler)handler
{
    responseHandler = [handler copy];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        __unused NSURLConnection *connectionNotNeeded = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    });
}


#pragma mark - Private API

- (NSMutableData *)responseData
{
    if (!_responseData) 
    {
        _responseData = _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    }

    return _responseData;
}


#pragma mark - URL Connection Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    responseHandler(nil, error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{    
    responseHandler([NSData dataWithData:self.responseData], nil);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSURLConnection retains its delegate, as well as itself while the connection is alive. So it's no coincidence that your solution works.

I can't find any official source on this, but it's been confirmed unofficially here on SO:

- [been having a little confusion about the retainCount of NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220902/been-having-a-little-confusion-about-the-retaincount-of-nsurlconnection)
- [Does a NSURLConnection retain its delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101867/does-a-nsurlconnection-retain-its-delegate)

Comment: Didn't know that about NSURLConnection - thanks, that's so helpful. I found that under [special considerations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJDDIDG) you'll see the official documentation of this.  About the `__unused`, I use that to suppress the warning `Expression result unused`.  Do you know another way to suppress that warning?

Comment: Also referencing `self` inside the block causes it to be retained.

Comment: @bearMountain The other way to suppress the warning is to not store the expression result! (as I have shown above). If you're not going to use the variable, there's no need to store it.

Comment: @Joe, yes, but this is a short-lived dispatch to the main thread, this block will not be alive for the duration of the connection (it's an asynchronous API).

Comment: @joerick In my Xcode, at least, the way you wrote it -will- generate the warning.  The warning comes from not using the result of the `init` expression. -try it

Comment: @bearMountain Interesting! I did not know that. I removed my nitpicking from the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend retaining `JCURLRequest` to be safe and correct. Take the following code for example:

```
@interface AsyncObject : NSObject
{
    BOOL ivar;
}
-(void)sendRequest:(void(^)()) callback;
@end

@implementation AsyncObject
-(void)sendRequest:(void (^)())callback
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Starting Long Async Task");
        sleep(15);
        //ivar = YES;
        NSLog(@"Calling Callback");
        callback();
    });
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Deallocated!");
}
@end

    ...
    [[[AsyncObject alloc] init] sendRequest:^{ NSLog(@"Called Back"); }];
```

If you leave `ivar` commented out the first thing that prints out is `Deallocated!` which means the `AsyncObject` gets deallocated before the request even finishes. Now if you uncomment `ivar` then `Deallocated!` is now last as it should be since the block properly retains the correct values. This could, however, be broken if the dispatch used a `_weak` reference to `self`.

```
__weak AsyncObject *self_ = self;
    ... //Inside gcd async method
    self_->ivar = YES; //This will break
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It turns out, as joerick pointed out, that `NSURLConnection` retains its delegate.  But, your answer still gave me great new insight.  It's very useful to use `-(void)dealloc` to track the lifecycle of an object if I'm unsure about it.  I think once I converted to ARC I abandoned all `retain`,`release`,`dealloc`, but it's very useful to remember that I can still implement `dealloc`!