# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler not working in iOS 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, ios4

I am using `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)` in my app. By using this my app is terminated in iOS 4.3 but it is working fine in iOS 5.0.

How to use this in iOS 4.3 can any one help me.

Comment: Step One: use a reasonably short title and format your code.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a full implementation that works for me. Feel free to rename it and add as a category on `NSURLConnection`, or just add it as a local method in the class you're working in.

```
-(void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request queue:(NSOperationQueue*)queue completionHandler:(void(^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))handler
{
    __block NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    __block NSError *error = nil;
    __block NSData *data = nil;

    // Wrap up synchronous request within a block operation
    NSBlockOperation *blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                     returningResponse:&response 
                                                 error:&error];
    }];

    // Set completion block
    // EDIT: Set completion block, perform on main thread for safety
    blockOperation.completionBlock = ^{

        // Perform completion on main queue
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            handler(response, data, error);
        }];
    };

    // (or execute completion block on background thread)
    // blockOperation.completionBlock = ^{ handler(response, data, error); };

    // Execute operation
    [queue addOperation:blockOperation];
}
```

***EDIT*** 
I had to modify the method because I was making UIKit calls in my completion block (e.g. updating labels etc). So it's actually a bit safer to call completion block on the main thread. (original version commented out)

Answer (score 2):

The method you are trying to use is only available on iOS 5. For earlier OSes, consider using

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
```

and wrapping it into a new thread to achieve async behavior.

Comment: Better to keep using the asynchronous behavior of `NSURLConnection`, scheduled on the main thread's run loop, with an appropriate delegate.

Comment: @KenThomases - any specific reason why that is better? Isn't what H2CO3 describes exactly what that convenience method is for? Is it just that you'd block a thread?

Comment: Yes. Since `NSURLConnection` provides an asynchronous mode, there's no reason to create a thread just to keep it from blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Both **H2CO3** and **Ken Thomases** suggestions are right.

In addition, you could take a look at [ios4-implementation-of-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829653/ios4-implementation-of-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequestqueuecompletio).

If you use the main queue as the queue where the completion handler performs, you could use (as **Tom** suggested) the delegate pattern. To avoid duplicate code, you could use a wrapper on `NSURLConnection` delegates mechanism.

In the other case, if you want to maintain the async behaviour and you don't want to deal with sync call (as **H2CO3** suggested, note that his suggestion is also valid) and the completion handler performs in a different queue, then I suggest you to wrap the async delegate pattern in a `NSOperation` class. This approach is quite difficult but you can find a good way of do this in [Concurrent Operations Demystified](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/) (see both the posts).

Hope it helps.